# Javascript function inside of string, how to add it to javascript to be called on for later

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to figure this out for a while, and I cannot wrap my head around how to do this. I dynamically created a function composed of different strings, and I would like to be able to turn this into actual javascript that can be called on.

I simplified this example but it still should help solve my problem.

```
var previewStringFunction = "function updateMap() {"
 + "some javascript code" + "}"
```

Comment: Why are you creating a function out of strings? You can `eval` it but it's bad practice.

Comment: What is the need to create dynamic function?

Comment: its part an application that allows people to see the script they are creating and I want to be able to execute it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a function by a string in JavaScript and staying in scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884637/calling-a-function-by-a-string-in-javascript-and-staying-in-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
<!--
function foo ()
{
  var script = document.createElement ('script');
  script.innerHTML = "function bar () {alert ('bar');}";
  body.appendChild (script);
}
// -->
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <input type="button" onclick="foo(); return false;" value="foo" />
    <input type="button" onclick="bar(); return false;" value="bar" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Button `foo` defines function, button `bar` calls it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use The eval() function for evaluating.

sample:

```
var strng = "function executeThs(){  alert('hello world'); }";// your string
eval(s);// evaluation of your function
executeThs();// calling function
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP